# Wordpress Style.css Header error

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, banner

I am currently working on a website and for some reason i'm baffled to the size of the logo/banner because the only option for the theme is to import a logo and use that. i uploaded the banner and i want it to go straight across and fit perfect? can anyone help me

[The website is here! [CLICK ME]](http://www.nettdesign.co.uk)

Here's the style.css
[CLICK ME TO GO THE PASTEBIN](https://pastebin.com/afbWwWS6)

```
 The code is more than the character limit
```

Please can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: You want to fit the logo to fit the screen right?

Comment: Yes. i've got round that but on the mobile version of the website it goes all funny. Please can you help me

Comment: You've put the logo inside the h1 tag get the image outside the h1 tag

Comment: Where have i done that? @Viira

Comment: search for "navbar-brand" you'll see that

Comment: I have removed it from the <h1> Tag and it still doesnt fit the whole screen

Comment: That's because of the bootstrap classes, ok now tell do you want to fit the image on the div or partially filled?

Comment: I just wan it to fit

Comment: Ok wait let me post a answer

Comment: Okay Thanks so much.

Comment: I've added my answer

Answer (score 0):

Was Messing Around with the CSS you provided. 
The container the header image is in is called navbar-brand.
In the CSS Ctrl+F and find it

add this snippet and it should do what you want.

```
.navbar-brand{
   width: 435% !important;
}
```

Now if change the size of your header image you're going to have to change the width percentage to match the new size with the header.

Comment: yeah in the css file you provided. Just use Ctrl+ F to search for ".navbar-brand"

Comment: There is an big big bug! Please help the nav bar goes through the banner!

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to tackle this issue, one make your navbar column to **col-sm-12** 
this way the width of the container will be 100% and it will take full width automatically.
Because currently it's getting **col-sm-4** which means 33.33%.

Adding width more than 100% never a good practice, you can add this code in your style sheet for second option.

```
.navbar-brand {
    width: 1140px !important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because your logo was stuck between the `h1` tag
After you remove it from the `h1` the default bootstrap classes comes with the default padding and margin.

Add this

```
.navbar-brand
{
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
```

and remove the bootstrap class `col-sm-3`
because  `.col-sm-3` only occupies the 25% of the space

since you need it to be fill the screen use `col-sm-12` it will occupy the 100% of the page.

To know more about bootstrap grids see here: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_basic.asp

And also bootstrap grids comes with default padding. Remove the padding to fit the screen

Add this

```
.col-sm-12
{
padding:0;
}

.row
{
margin:0;
}
```

You'll have your image full sized now.
Hope I helped.

Comment: add these in your style.css file

Comment: And where should i remove the .col? and remove the .col

Comment: see above navbar-brand class there is class named <div class="col-sm-3 clearfix"> change that to <div class="col-sm-12 clearfix">

Comment: Urm... The image is full size but it goes through the navbar... http://nettdesign.co.uk

Comment: recheck your html structure mate.

Comment: To me everything looks fine.